# Which WinAPI library is best for uploading a file to a server

Tags: c++, winapi, uploading

I have a WinAPI C++ application & I need to upload a file to my server. I want to use native WinAPI libraries/header files to upload the file so that my application will work on windows platforms 2000 & up & because I want to learn how to do it in win32 which I think will be fun. This means that I dont want to use a 3rd party library but learn how to do it the native WinAPI way.

**Which of the following "Libraries"/Methods would be best for my needs?**
- WinHTTP
- WinSock
- WinINet

Maybe there are better WinAPI libraries that I haven't mentioned aswell?

The method of uploading I would use is either TCP, HTTP or UDP but I am not sure which transfer protocol would be best for what I am doing? Which would you suggest?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the protocol, either WinHTTP or WinInet. Sockets are too low-level.

If the server supports only FTP, then WinInet. If it's HTTP upload (via POST or PUT), then WinHTTP. The thing with HTTP uploads is that there's no single, universally accepted way to do that, and server admins are often reluctant to allow for two-way HTTP file transfer. FTP, on the other hand, is a tried and true workhorse.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously WinInet or WinHTTP. And using HTTP would be best.